# LibGDX/Android developement: Where should I create BitmapFonts?

Tags: java, android, bitmap, libgdx, screen

I know how loading new BitmapFonts in LibGDX works but now I am worried about using the font on multiple menus. I don't want to constantly create new BitmapFonts on every screen, do I?

Where should I create a BitmapFont in my LibGDX game so every menu can use it, without re-creating the font on each menu?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally I wouldn't worry about creating new BitmapFonts in each screen, libGDX will manage the bitmap in memory and the GC will take care of unused objects. Just make sure you're not creating the objects in any update or render methods and dispose objects as appropriate.

If you're worried about repeating code in every screen you can also extend your screens from an abstract screen. I've outlined this in another stackoverflow question here  [Reuse code when using screens in Libgdx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21923141/reuse-code-when-using-screens-in-libgdx/21923236#21923236). Just create a protected BitmapFont in the abstract screen and then you can reuse it in any screen that you extend from your abstract class.

Comment: Aaaaaaand that is exactly what I want! Thank you much! =D